# mark() method of StringReader

Tags: java, stringreader

My question pertains to the mark() method of Java's StringReader. Here is my scenario:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader("Test123");

reader.mark(0);
boolean bool = doSomething(reader)//reads from reader with calls to mark() inside
if (bool == false) {
    reader.reset();
}

doSomethingElse(reader);
```

I want to recover my reader back to its original state if doSomething() returns false. Because reset() will only reset the reader back to the previously-called mark, and there are marks called from within the doSomething() method, it doesn't refer to the mark called one line before entering the doSomething() method. Is there a possible workaround to this? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you know that `doSomething()` calls `mark()`, there's no point in calling `mark()` before that.
2. Instead of resetting the `StringReader`, you can just create a new `StringReader` from the same string.

Comment: The problem with that is the StringReader is being passed to this function from a higher-level function, and the reference to that needs to be maintained throughout.

Comment: OK, you didn't mention that. Do you have control of this higher function? If so, you could write a custom class that works like StringReader, but allows random access.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to mark it before you reset:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader("Test123");

boolean bool = doSomething(reader)//reads from reader with calls to mark() inside
if (bool == false) {
    reader.mark(0);
    reader.reset();
}

doSomethingElse(reader);
```

If you can't do that, you can wrap the initial mark position and reader in a custom object:

```
class MyReader {
   private int mark = 0;
   private StringReader reader;

   MyReader( StringReader reader, int mark ) {
      this.reader = reader;
      this.mark = mark;
   }

   public StringReader getReader() { return reader; }

   public void hardReset() {
      reader.mark(mark);
      reader.reset();
   }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader("Test123");
MyReader mr = new MyReader( reader, 0 );
boolean bool = doSomething(mr); // mr.getReader().mark(i); 
if (bool == false) {
     mr.hardReset();
}

doSomethingElse(mr);
```

Comment: Marking immediately before i reset defeats the purpose. It is going to reset back to what was marked one line before, which isn't what was there before doSomething() was called.

Comment: I see where your confusion lies. mark(0) doesn't always mean the 0 index of the string that was originally entered in the constructor. It means the 0 index in relation to where the pointer is currently at....So if you have called read() twice, mark(0) will now refer to index 2.

Comment: Ah.  Then this wouldn't work as intended.  Copying is the better solution.